# Should good answers given outside (in private) be upvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I had a "How do I do X?" question, and the answer came in the form of:

> I have code that I can share, please contact me.

I got exactly what I needed, at no cost to me. I feel grateful, but I others won't get the benefit exclusively from reading.

EDIT: After the feed back from stackexchange I am not so sure of the following.

I want to clarify that I think is is perfectly acceptable to post an offer to help, and suggest/ask to be contacted by email. There could be many reasons for it, and as a whole these responses do help the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Please [email me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131293/should-good-answers-given-outside-in-private-be-upvoted#doh), I have a comment about this I'd like to share.

Comment: So this is like the opposite of plz-send-teh-codez?

Comment: I really appreciate the answer feedback, it was an honest question. On the other hand I am disappointed that my question got downvoted by twelve. I simply will ask the person who responded to share the code. I am editing my question to see if my acceptance of posting an private offer to help was the reason for downvoting.

Comment: On the whole it benefits only you.

Comment: @Won't Why would this question just benefit me? It may be a repeat of the FAQ. But >this< question would benefit anyone who does not know the answer.

Comment: No, that was my one-line answer to your initial question.  As to your comment about the downvotes, people are saying "no, allowing this kind of answer is detrimental to the community."

Answer (score 27):

No, an offer to help outside of Stack Overflow isn't an answer at all and should be deleted.  One of the reasons Stack Overflow was started to begin with was that helping people one at a time via email doesn't scale.  If you got a solution, that's great and you should post it, but the offer along with an email address doesn't help anyone else.

Comment: I suggest that others confronted with this question simply ask the person who replied to post the code. There is no need to jump the gun on an honest offer to help.